# Akka infinite loop dead letter

Tags: akka

I have two UntypedActors which will exchange messages in infinite loop.

```
class ActorA extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            ActorRef actorb = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class));
            actorb.tell(0, getSelf());
        }
        if (message instanceof Integer) {
            int count = (Integer) message;
            System.out.println("ActorA: " + count++);
            getSender().tell(count, getSelf());
        }

    }
}
class ActorB extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {

        if (message instanceof Integer) {
            int count = (Integer) message;
            System.out.println("ActorB: " + count++);
            getSender().tell(count, getSelf());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a code which will execute above actors.

```
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("bb");

    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(ActorA.class), "ddd");
    master.tell("Msg", master);
    system.shutdown();
```

After many iterations suddenly I receive:

from Actor[akka://bb/user/ddd/$a#-1708720414] to Actor[akka://bb/user/ddd#250962293] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.

My question is why after multiple loops between two actors finally I received dead letter ? I know that its connected with memory allocation but I received only over 100 loops and dead letter appeared.

Comment: It works alright for me. Continues forever

Comment: My bad. Problem was with  system.shutdown(); I started ActorSystem and in no time I executed shutdown on it so actors couldn;t perform its job